# MVC - use different controller under specific circumstances

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Customer controller that deals with customer products, information and what not.  Some products have specialisations that I want handle slightly differently so need a process of doing that.  Currently I have hard coded in `if` statements to see if a customer has that product or not, and if it has, it'll add the extra navigation elements etc.

What I think might be a better way is to have a Controller that inherits off my customer controller but adds the extra functionality.  It'd then be pretty nifty if I could, upon receiving the request, check which Customer derived controller has a function that matches the request i.e. `ViewSpecialProduct` and then invokes that as opposed to the vanilla customer controller.

Are there easier ways? If not how do I accomplish the above? I don't know enough about routes and the controller initialisation process yet.

Thanks

Comment: chris, are these if **statements** part of the controller action or embedded within the view??

Comment: Hey Jim.  Currently as part of the controller.  If a certain product is selected I create new nav elements that are sent to the view.   But the functions that control them are currently part of the main controller, I feel they should be part of another controller?

Comment: ok, if the product 'specialties' are a **known in advance** scenario, you could create interfaces for those addtional sub-classes. on populating the product object, you would define the product using the appropriate interface (rather than the concrete implementation). this would allow you to have the option of having interface specific partialviews and/or logic to determine how to handle the different product implementations within the controller action. i would stick to the single controller but treat the interface implementations where required.

Comment: chris - i guess what i'm advocating is some sort of DI put in place. this may be helpful: http://www.kevinrohrbaugh.com/blog/2009/8/7/using-ninject-2-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Controller Factory that derives from `DefaultControllerFactory` and overrides the `GetControllerInstance`.  I'm not sure how you're performing the customer check but it could look something like this:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == typeof(DefaultProductController))
        {                
            if(// is special customer)
                return new SpecialProductController();
            else
                return new DefaultProductController();
        }
    }
}
```

You then set the new ControllerFactory in Global.asax Application_Start via `ControllerBuilder.Current`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm after - thanks.  I'll report back once I've got something working

Comment: I think this helps me. Thanks.  Your `GetControllerInstance` implementaiton is missing a return at the end though: `return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);`

Answer (score 0):

Because of where it occurs in the life cycle, you probably don't want to do this with routing.  MvcContrib has code available for a SubController http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/mvccontrib-latest-release-now-with-subcontroller-support/.  Also, you could just create another controller, by either injecting the controller factory reference into the controller, or by creating a controller manually and returning its action, (but if you want this to work, you have to remember to initalize it with the ControllerContext).